# What a beautiful canyon

Tags: cipher, steganography

My friend sent me an image of this beautiful **canyon** and asked me to work out where he is. More specifically, his latitude and longitude.

The only issue is that he's in Europe and this photo is of the Grand **Canyon**!

Can you help me find out where he is?

[image: canyon.jpg]

(It's fictional -- no friend involved. Just a backstory.)

---

**Hint 1**

> Check the tags!

**Hint 2**

> Half the clue is in one place, half the clue is in another.

Comment: He's in Europe. Obviously!

Comment: @Rubio Not quite what I mean... 

Comment: @RewanDemontay Nope. Check the tags!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I like steganography:

> In image (edit image as text) is link to https://pastebin.com/uZzKFKhN
>  That has base64 text and decoding it gives https://gist.github.com/davwheat/
>  Which I'm not sure where to go next, but - that user seems to be from UK? (I could try to measure degrees in [that image](https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/7406822?s=400&v=4), but it feels like long shot) (there is also "022121001695" and "Murray Foubister" in image, but I guess that is some random information)

Some additional info:

> There is "DYzMmM1NjZkYzQ1M2U1MjA0YWE4MDcxZmFjODk5MmE=" in comment of picture, but it is not correct Base64.
>  With joining with first Base64 code (or concatenation) it leads to https://gist.github.com/davwheat/4632c566dc453e5204aa8071fac8992a
>  In the name of file is another Base64 code "M3dvcmRz==" that gives "3words" that looks like it should be applied to text "///tiaqsf.rapiotgs.gpchdlr".
>  But that could be used in: https://what3words.com/ where those three words would be used something like https://what3words.com/tiaqsf.rapiotgs.gpchdlr

And:

> With vigenere key "canyon" it gives us location https://what3words.com/rinses.packages.trouble which looks like airport in Denmark.

Comment: Murray Foubister appears to be the original photographer, he has a Flickr account with a lot of nature photography and a lot of the south rim photos on Wikimedia commons are credited to him :)

Comment: @JanIvan You're getting quite close. Murray is just the original capturer and has no relation to the question. You're missing part of the URL. The second half is located elsewhere.

Comment: @DavidWheatley Well I think I'm still missing something, problem is that picture is exacly same as on wiki, except some "text" inside. I found plenty of stuff, but I don't see any that I should use. Like: 0D85AB2F1400C1EE53FF419BE361802E, W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d = [42!573], 0000413cf8, 022121001695, E49oi, 5050386e82, 7406822, maybe Canyon or canyon.jpg, and it could fit https://gist.github.com/davwheat/???/ or https://puu.sh/???/ or https://pastebin.com/???/ My best bet was something like https://gist.github.com/davwheat/[42!573]/

Comment: @JanIvan Checking the text contents of the file itself won't help. It's something else to do with the data for the image.